# Html: Link on Picture

Tags: html, css

I need help at the pictures of my Website. 
I want to have the link from the Website, I have the picture at the picture on my Website. But I don't know how I can create it.

```
<div class="mySlides fade" align="center">
<div  class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
<img src="bilder/testen.jpg"
style="width:100%">
<div  class="text"><b  class="bru">Anwendungen testen und anpassen</b></div>
</div>
```

I hope it is understandable and you can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: do you want the image be a link to otherpage/site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `a` tag and inside set `img`

[Learn about `a` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

```html
<div class="mySlides fade" align="center">
<div  class="numbertext">2 / 5</div>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">
  <img src="bilder/testen.jpg" style="width:100%">
</a>
<div  class="text"><b  class="bru">Anwendungen testen und anpassen</b></div>
</div>
```

Comment: happy to help:)